# Не могу проверить статус СEPH

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-mint, кластер

Ситуация следующая. Установил cephadm, прописал команды "cephadm add-repo --release octopus" и "cephadm install ceph-common" для упрощенно работы CEPH. После этого, на одной из нод должна работать команда "ceph status", однако, она не работает

[CODE]root@CEPH01:~# ceph status
[errno 13] RADOS permission denied (error connecting to the cluster)[/CODE]

В чем может быть проблема??

Comment: Кейринг на месте?

Comment: Прошу прощения, не знаю что это, не силен в CEPH, если честно.

Comment: Если вы говорили про ключи, то bootstrap мною был успешно установлен. Но на любую команду ceph (кроме ceph -v) он реагирует ошибкой, описанной выше